# Swagger not loading - Failed to load API definition: error undefined message

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-3.1, webapi

As I tried to change one public method to private. The issue will be gone.

But when I defined the public method on both method as the below controller code, it will bring up the error.

Anyone help/advice if possible would be really appreciate

WEBLABController.cs

```
[Route("api/SearchLABResults")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SearchLABResults([FromBody] SP_GET_LABResult_Overview.input data)
    {
        IActionResult response = Unauthorized();
        ......
        return response;
    }
```

AuthenticationController.cs

```
[Route("api/GenerateToken")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GenerateToken([FromBody] AuthenticationModel.input data)
    {
        IActionResult response = Unauthorized();
        ......
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Check other methods to be certain there are no duplicates route. Swagger would not launch if it detects methods with the same route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you scroll down the swagger view, You see that every model you are using is shown there. Swagger needs that those names be unique.

`SP_GET_LABResult_Overview.input` and `AuthenticationModel.input` are both generate `input` schema and that cause InvalidOperationException.

Try to change one of the input classes to something else or change their schema on the fly like this.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.ToString());
});
```